# reset or completely remove an installation/htop

Tags: command-line, package-management, gnome-terminal, virtual-terminal, htop

I usually use htop in tty when I need to kill a program... or whatever hangs or slows down my pc,now I screwed it up.

I tried making changes in htop from the 'setup' option which is accessed by pressing F2 key,and by mistake filled the screen and now I can't see a single process and can't even delete the widget or the process viewer(whatever it is called) from the screen as my screen is filled and can't see any options to delete them.![This is how my screen looks now in fullscreen terminal window,can't be scrolled so can't view other options to delete them][1]

Here's the screenshot : http://postimg.org/image/ez8k1f8c3/

I've tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge htop`
and `sudo apt-get remove htop`
also 'completely remove' from synaptic manager,but no success as the settings remain on the pc even after removing the package.

Any way by which I could re-install it by completely removing it's whole settings or options by which I could remove those widgets off screen?

Answer (score 15):

htop stores its settings under `~/.config/`. Personal settings stored under `$HOME` are never removed when you remove a package. To reset these settings, just remove the configuration file:

```
rm -fv ~/.config/htop/htoprc
```